# Save GoogleGraph as Vector Image

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, svg

I'm working on dynamically creating a PDF document of analytics. The graph etc are created using the Google Graph API. So what I am doing is changing the graphs into images and then loading them into a webpage which is then been converted to a PDF using the mpdf (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) library.

This is the tutorial I am followng: http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html and I have corrected the code to:

```
function getImgData(chartContainer) {
var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);


canvas.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'position: absolute; ' +
    'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
    'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvg(canvas, svg);
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
return imgData;
 }
```

based on advice from this thread: [Save Google charts as a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824096/save-google-charts-as-a-image)

However, the image that is outputted is in PNG format and I need it to be SVG, I thought it might just be a case of changing this line:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

to:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/svg");
```

However this isnt working, can anyone please point me in the right direction? or if there is a better and free way to convert Google Graphs into pdf I would be very happy to explore other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the var "svg" contains the SVG. You do not need to convert it. So:

```
function getSvgData(chartContainer) {
var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
return svg;
}
```