# Canvas elements not working in IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

I have used this tutorial: [Save Google charts as a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824096/save-google-charts-as-a-image) which converts Google Graphs into an image and then saves it for me.

It's working perfectly and it achieves this by creating a canvas element and then drawing the graph onto it.

However and typical with IE its doesnt work with any browser lower than 9. Which is a huge problem as most of our clients are still in the dark ages. sadly.

Can anyone recommend a good solution to this or has any of you got any experience to share on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use [ExCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)

Modern browsers like Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera support the HTML5 canvas tag to allow 2D command-based drawing. ExplorerCanvas brings the same functionality to Internet Explorer. To use, web developers only need to include a single script tag in their existing web pages.

<kbd>[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)</kbd>

Comment: Just note you [can't extract data with exCanvas (toDataURL)](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=77) so I guess it's not usable in that sense since OP need to save images..

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Just gone through with your link, even I was not aware about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@wizkid's answer is a good suggestion in it self - however, the only problem is that [exCanvas do not support toDataURL()](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=77) and won't due to the nature of it using VML. This means you won't be able to use it to save out images.

**Update**

You *can* use flash to solve this problem. There are two solutions available:

- http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/
- http://flashcanvas.net/

Both of these should be able to save out bitmap images from the "canvas" as png and jpeg (ref: [fxcanvas](http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/#Compatibility), [flashcanvas](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/canvas-api)). This would of course require the client to have Flash player installed.

The third option is to use a server as a proxy (or as processor) for Google charts.