# PHP file_get_contents convert & into &amp

Tags: php, file-get-contents

The mentioned link in variable $link is redirect to product page. Its working fine when i call/open it in browser. But it does not work in PHP file_get_contents function.

**My Code:**

```
    $url = "750651";
    $link = "http://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?storeId=10301&catalogId=10701&langId=-1&keyword=$url";
    $link = str_replace('&amp;','&',$link);
    $res = file_get_contents(html_entity_decode(urldecode($link)));
```

Error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?storeId=10301&amp;catalogId=10701&amp;langId=-1&amp;keyword=750651): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

How can I prevent conversion of `&` into `&amp;` in file_get_contents functions
I also have tried following code but no success

```
 $link = "http://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?";
 $options = array("storeId"=>"10301","catalogId"=>"10701","langId"=>"-1","keyword"=>$url);
 $link .= http_build_query($options,'','&');
 $res = file_get_contents($link);
```

Comment: The link you have responds with a 302, it redirect to another link. This is the reason you are having problems. `http://www.costco.com/Perfect-Smile%C2%AE-EASY-CLICK-Teeth-Whitening-Pen.product.100036334.html?catalogId=10701&keyword=750651&langId=-1&storeId=10301`

Comment: @RonniSkansing Yes it is redirecting so need next page content. How is it possible?

Comment: Yes you could either look at the response and make a new request or try  out the comment I added to the other answer with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)` also if you search "file_get_contents redirect" you will find some stuff that is readable with other people asking something very similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found alternative function to do this. I hope this would be use full.

```
function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

        if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
            foreach( $headers as $value ) {
                if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                    return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    } else {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}
```

To see results

```
$lurl=get_fcontent($link);
echo $lurl[0];
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402193/3466544

Answer (score 1):

I used it this way:

```
$myURL = 'http://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?';   
$options = array("storedId"=>$10301,"câtlogId"=>10701,"langId"=>-1,"keyword"=>$url);
$myURL .= http_build_query($options,'','&');

$myData = file_get_contents("$myURL");
```

And it ran well. Try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the urldecode and entity_decode, or do those before the string_replacement

```
$link = "http://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?storeId=10301&catalogId=10701&langId=-1&keyword=$url";
$link = str_ireplace('&amp;','&', html_entity_decode(urldecode($link)));
$res = file_get_contents($link);
```

You cannot get every site via file_get_contents, this because of the same-origin policy. The site owner should open up Access-Control-Allow-Origin for that to work. You can however download the site via CURL, that goes something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if you want to follow redirects
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I do var_dump($data); but it returns empty string '' (length=0)

Comment: How does the URL look if you echo it? You should look in the page source, not the output or inspect element feature in webkit.

Comment: There is nothing in page source too :(

Comment: Do you have cURL installed? You can check by creating a new php file with the line `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Yes, its installed and enabled.
cURL support  enabled

Comment: `You cannot get every site via file_get_contents, this because of the same-origin policy. The site owner should open up Access-Control-Allow-Origin for that to work`, it has nothing to do same-origin policy.

Comment: Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)` to make it work.