# PHP Error "file_get_contents & Authorization Required" in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authorization, file-get-contents

i got a problem with one of my wordpress plugins. When i activate it this message shows on top of the screen.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://gruender-news24.de/wp-content/plugins/ultproteam_/includes/../css/font-awesome.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required in /mnt/web7/e3/69/5941469/htdocs/WordPress_08/wp-content/plugins/ultproteam_/includes/plugin-class.php on line 336
```

This code is on line 336.

```
$pTsubject = file_get_contents( $this->mainPath . '/css/font-awesome.css');
```

Im not really familiar to php and i couldnt figure it out by myself.
This seems to offer a solution but im not able to "transform" it on my special problem.

http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-authentication-and-filegetcontents

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Have you protected your wordpress installation with a httaccess/htpasswd basic authentication to permit anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() utilizes the [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) wrappers, therefore it is restricted from accessing URLs through the allow_url_fopen option within php.ini

OR

try using CURL.

lots of good answers in what looks like a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/file-get-contents-returning-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed).