# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I am trying to use wp-authentication from another server. So I have login.php file:

```
<?php
    $content=file_get_contents("http://xxx/custom_login.php");
    echo $content;
?>
```

and custom_login.php, on another site:

```
<?php 
    require('wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
```

I think this is where it breaks. Although, when called on its own, custom_login.php works fine.

Can I fix this?

Comment: have to tried curl_exec() ?

Comment: I have. It doesn't break then, but I don't know how to use the response of **curl_exec($curl_handle);**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/why-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed

Comment: Ok, simply echoing **curl_exec($curl_handle);* solved it. Thanks!