# geoplugin is not working in live evironment but in local system its working

Tags: php

I am getting this error when i am uploading in the server

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=207.46.13.5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why file\_get\_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/why-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

Answer (score 0):

You getting 403 error, so, it seems you need to register on geoplugin.net and add your live domain to some kind of whitelist. There is info about it in [quickstart](http://www.geoplugin.com/quickstart)

Comment: I have already registered in geoplugin.net with my domain name still sometime its works and sometime its doesn't work.