# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 404 Not Found

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents in my site xyz.com to get an image in demo.com but it return an error:

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(http://demo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2-1.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in **/home/xyz.com/public_html/core_functions.php** on line **113**

That file http://demo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2-1.jpg is exist. But file_get_contents warning it 404.

Comment: demo.com is a custom record in your hosts file? if so, try to restart apache and clear dns cache

Comment: i was test again with another link, only link in demo.com is 404. Please tell my why?

Comment: I had the same problem which i fixed by enabling Output_buffering on the server  http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering Which can be enabled in php.ini

Comment: Please let us know if it helps.

Comment: Not working for me, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)