# Error when using fopen() in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');

   $file_handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");

?>
```

The above script results in

> Warning: fopen(...) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request ...

Notes
(i) allow_url_fopen is open for both local/master value
(ii) I'm running the php script on xampp/windows 8
(iii) get_headers(), http_get(), and file_get_contents() works with no error.

Please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: Should we assume that the actual URL you are using is not `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Is there any other information in the PHP Error log?

Comment: I advise you to use CURL to read webpages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

Comment: It didn't work with example.com or any other websites

Comment: there is no php error file generated

Comment: I've a problem with curl too, I've got a blank page.MNo error information given.

Comment: I suspect it is a xampp or windows 8 problem. What should I be checking?

Comment: I got a blank page when using the code at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed[/link]

Comment: yes, now try to print the handle.

Comment: This is the code,

    <?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       ini_set('display_errors', '1');


       # Define the file you want to download
       $target      = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
       $file_handle = fopen($target, "r");

       print $file_handle;


    ?>



This is the error
Warning: fopen(http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\examples\LISTING_3_1b.php on line 8