# php:How to fix ''Array ( )''? am trying to get contents from each individual file in a folder

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-5.6

```
    <?php

        function cmp($a, $b) {
            if (filemtime($a) == filemtime($b))
                return 0;

            return (filemtime($a) < filemtime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
        }


        $files = glob("/Users/xx/Desktop/2011/cdr/*.cdr");
        usort($files, "cmp");

        foreach($files as $file)

            //echo $file . "<br />";
            // echo "$file was last modified: " . date ("d-m-Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file))."\n";


    $file1 = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


    $arr1 = explode("\n", $file1);


    $data1 = array();



     foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
 $split = explode(";", $value);

 $keys = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}
 print_r($data1);
?>
```

I am trying to get contents from each file but it keep getting below

> Array ( )

Question is how can i fix the error when am trying to get contents from each individual file in a folder? Should i make a loop to read from each file separately ?

Comment: Are you trying to access a local file (not on server such as `localhost`) using php? I don't think it's possible, but I assume that if it is possible it should be done using `file://` protocol (e.g.: `file://C:\Users\xx\Desktop\2011\cdr\*.cdr`)

Comment: İ tried that too. its a directory from my computer file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2011/cdr/.I tried it too but still get the error

Comment: Then it's not possible. Work with some framework (such as wampserver or xampp) and run `localhost` on your system, then put the contents from this file inside your server and try to read it

Comment: If you want to access local DIR/File directly - no. This is not how PHP works. But after uploading to a server you can manipulate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

Comment: @ Kris Roofe errors might be similar but its not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = glob("/Users/xx/Desktop/2011/cdr/*.cdr");
```

This call to `glob()` will return an array of absolute paths like:

```
"/Users/xx/Desktop/2011/cdr/example.cdr"
```

The path is part of the returned value! (This is unlike some other functions like `readdir()`.) You don't need to append the path again when you call `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Well, the array you're printing at the end is created by `$data1 = array();`… what did you _expect_ to happen?!

Comment: Thanks. i must be really tired