# PHP file_get_contents() throws error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! <!doctype html>"

Tags: php

I'm trying to return JSON results from a page but I get the following error using file_get_contents(): " failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  "

Can someone tell me why I get this error?

```
<?

$newURL = 'https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=Spicy 
Cranberry Cavolo Nero (Kale)';



$returnedData = file_get_contents($newURL);

?>
```

Comment: Any reason not to have "https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=Spicy%20Cranberry%20Cavolo%20Nero%20(Kale)" instead of what you have right now? With %20 for each space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP file\_get\_contents() returns "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

Comment: have your tried to escape the parameters correctly? for example, replace the spaces with `%20` in the url.

Comment: @RAZERZ  I tried doing a urlencode on the query itself but it gives me a different error (Too many request):

    $baseURL = 'https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?';

    $query = urlencode("count=10&offset=1&q=Spicy Cranberry Cavolo 
    Nero (Kale)");

    $composedURL = $baseURL.$query;


    $returnedData = file_get_contents($composedURL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never use `<? ?>`. Use only `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>`
2. urlencode() use only on values of your parameters, not on the whole parameter's line.
3. file_get_contents() is not a really good method to receive data from the outer servers. Better use CURL.

   ```
   <?php

   // Your URL with encoded parts
   $newURL = 'https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q='.urlencode('Spicy Cranberry Cavolo Nero (Kale)');

   // This is related to the specifics of this api server, 
   // it requires you to provide useragent header
   $options = array(
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'any-user-agent-you-want',
   );

   // Preparing CURL
   $curl_handle = curl_init($newURL);

   // Setting array of options
   curl_setopt_array( $curl_handle, $options );

   // Getting the content
   $content = curl_exec($curl_handle);

   // Closing conenction
   curl_close($curl_handle);

   // From this point you have $content with your JSON data received from API server

   ?>
   ```

Comment: and you can send POST requests with curl as well