# Laravel Registration Page Authentication Error

Tags: laravel

After submitting new user's information on my laravel website, it pops up an error page with 'Whoops something went wrong'. Who can help with this please? I'm new to laravel.

Comment: Check in your `.env` file the variables and it's values must be like this `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true` and try again to look out the error you're getting.

Comment: ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_get_contents(https://...@gmail.com&amp;route_id=117): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Comment: are you using curl in code ?

Answer (score 0):

If Your are using cURL

or

[Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed)

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://###.##.##.##/mp/get?mpsrc=http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/11111.mpg&mpaction=convert format=flv');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

?>
```