# How to retrieve image from public folder and convert to base64 in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, base64

I want to get the image file from my public folder which I stored all of my images, then convert to `base64`. I will use the `base64` image to view it on PDF using `pdfmake` in dataTables, because my dataTable cell have an Image called `avatar`, and as I've searched it needs to convert image to base64 to able to view in PDF.

Now I use `file_get_contents` to retrieve my image, but my page is too much load I guess it's around 5mins, and after throws and error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`.

```
{{ file_get_contents( asset('files/user_avatar.png') ) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between svg and (jpg-png-jpeg) when you encoding to base64. You can use basically png extension when you working with png image. But you cant use svg basically. You need svg+xml when you working with svg.

```
function img_enc_base64 ($filepath){   // img_enc_base64() is manual function you can change the name what you want.

    if (file_exists($filepath)){

        $filetype = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($filetype==='svg'){
            $filetype .= '+xml';
        }

        $get_img = file_get_contents($filepath);
        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($get_img );
    }
}
```

so now

```
echo img_enc_base64('file_path');  // is your base64 code of image

<img src="<?php echo img_enc_base64('file_path');?>" alt="">  // is your image
```

file_path example:  pics/my_book.png

Comment: still too long to load, if I add the `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: replace it to $get_img = fread(fopen($filepath, 'rb'), filesize($filepath));  and try again

Comment: still same ? Try running the function I wrote as a separate test from the project. Then if it's still the same, pay attention to the file size. Or can be a problem with the configuration settings

Comment: I got error on `file_get_contents failed to open stream http request failed` **Answer of Amaan** is working on my live server but still too long to load in my local.

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed    when uses with fread() ...  it's working  in my server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not friendly with `Laraval` but I have a **tested** answer written in `PHP`

```
<?php
    $path = "files/user_avatar.png";
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    # print to make sure that it is working or not
    echo $base64."<br>";
    # Or, show it as a clean image
    echo '<img scr="'.$base64.'" height="150" width="150">';
?>
```

**Edited:**

According to [`Jin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8095851/jin),
Above snippet not working just because of `file_get_contents` function.

**Solution:**

Use `curl_get_contents()` instead of `file_get_contents`

**`curl_get_contents()`**

```
function curl_get_contents($url){
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
```

After replacing `file_get_contents` into `curl_get_contents`

```
$path = "files/user_avatar.png";
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = curl_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
# print to make sure that it is working or not
echo $base64."<br>";
# Or, show it as a clean image
echo '<img scr="'.$base64.'" height="150" width="150">';
```

> **Still taking too much time to load?**
> Try to check your file size or try
> to check `Server-Configuration`

Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: Hi, still too long to load. it might because of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Don't worry I have a solution

Comment: Hi again, still taking too much in my local, but it's okay in my server, where view the server-configuration in local?

Comment: Can you check it on another `Server` or try to change this `user_avatar.png` file to another, Just pickup one transparent image from this page https://www.cleanpng.com/free/avatar-.html

Comment: In my local server? what is the name of file? `base64` image is now showing on live server but still not viewing on the PDF, I am using `pdfmake` and `datatables`

Comment: You can use any server and any image from above URL

Comment: And `PHP` code is not responsible for slow load this is because you are using `pdfmake` and `datatables`try to use jquery

Comment: If someone is asking Laravel and not PHP, you shouldn't post a PHP answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it should be:

```
$path = 'files/user_avatar.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

bear in mind that this will enlarge the data by 33%, and you'll have problems with files whose size exceed your memory_limit.

Comment: Hi, it's still too long to load. It might be `file_get_contents()` ?