# failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, file, nginx, error-handling

I am using code like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://example.com/file.txt');
```

In response I get an error:

> **Warning:** file_get_contents(https://example.com/file.txt): failed to
> open stream: Cannot assign requested address in
> /sites/example.com/test.php
> on line **2**

As I understand it, the server for some reason forbids accessing the file_get_contents () function if the file is located on the same server. Because queries like this work:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://example.org');
```

Help me please. In which direction to dig?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/php-file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed . use CURL or urlencode

Answer (score -1):

in /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.1.1 example.com example
```

replaced by

```
external_ip of example.com example
```

Comment: Why would DNS be the issue here? Manually assigning IPs to site names is almost never a sustainable solution.

Comment: I don't know but this is work